# How to read only non-adjacent columns copied from Excel into a pandas DF via clipboard?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I love using pd.read_clipboard() to quickly import tabular data from Excel into a DataFrame in pandas.

However, if I have highlighted non-adjacent columns in Excel before I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy them to the clipboard, what gets imported into my DF will include all of the intervening columns that were sandwiched between the non-adjacent columns that I had selected for copying.
(I'm currently using Windows 10 & Excel 2013).

This is annoying and incovenient.
I suspect that the problem may emanate from Excel or the Windows clipboard, since I also get the intervening (tab-separated) columns when I paste into Sublime Text 3.

If I paste into a blank worksheet, I only get the highlighted columns I want, and this has been my work-around (creating an interim Excel sheet that I then copy and import into pandas). It's a decent workaround, but I'm looking for something faster, since I go back and forth between Excel and pandas MANY times per day.

I am aware that the problem goes away if I HIDE the columns in Excel before copying them (whether by the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> shortcut or by grouping the intervening columns I want to hide), but neither of these are suitable, since it manipulates my current view/design of my Excel worksheet (and anyway Windows 10 has clobbered the "unhide columns" shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)... although <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> still works).

The problem does not go away when the intervening columns that I don't want are visible (thus it doesn't matter if I hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to select only visible cells before I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

I'm looking for a solution that is simple and fast, preferably an alternative shortcut to use in Excel, or a universal kwarg I can use for pd.read_clipboard().

The documentation for pd.read_clipboard() says to look at the keywords from pd.read_table(), but I can't figure out which might help.  Again, I suspect the problem has to do with the clipboard on the Windows end, but I have searched and searched online and can't find anything except third-party commercial Excel plugins which claim to be able to help with copying non-contiguous cells.

Comment: This is an excel problem and not a pandas issue. Try pasting into notepad and not a blank worksheet to test. Also there is a pandas function to read excel files: [`pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). You can use the `usecols` argument to specify the columns you want.

Comment: @pault, I already acknowledged this, as the problem persists when I paste into Sublime Text 3.

Comment: This is true, but you have a lot of text in your question so forgive me for not thoroughly reading it all carefully. Anyway I think the way to go is avoid the cut-and-paste and use `read_excel`.

Comment: @pault, yes, forgive me for putting a lot of text, but I have read Stackoverflow questions for many years and know that I should pre-emptively detail some of the unsuitable workarounds that people will suggest.   (For instance, I am not interested in using pd.read_excel() nor any of the similar options because they deal with using a temporary file as an intermediate step.  I am already using a temporary blank worksheet as an intermediate step).  I am also looking for a generic solution. I do this MANY times a day, so I can't be inputting the "usecols" kwarg. My workaround is already faster)

Comment: There is no workaround AFAIK. Excel allows you to copy and paste non-adjacent columns as a convenience. It's unlikely that you'll be able to maintain this feature outside of excel without a third party app. That being said, I will (for the final time) advocate for `read_excel()`. There is no need for temporary files- just specify the same file you are working on. The `usecols` arg will accept an Excel style range as an input (e.g. `“A:E”` or `“A,C,E:F”`). IMHO, this is easier than copy and paste but maybe someone will have a better solution.

Comment: thanks, @pault. pd.read_excel() could work in some cases, but it is unsatisfactory to me for a few reasons: first, I have to navigate my file structure to find the actual workbook file that I need to reference; then, I would have to reference the particular worksheet I am pasting from; and finally, I often have rows filtered based on other columns, for the particular view I am working on, and thus I'd have to code those filters into pandas as well.